# PHP out of memory error does not reflect memory_limit setting in php.ini

Tags: php, composer-php, wampserver, contao

When I try to install a package to Contao using the Composer client I get an error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217728 bytes) in phar://D:/wamp/www/myproject/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220

I am **really** confused. My PHP memory limit is set at 512M. `phpinfo()` confirms it. But 1073741824 is a gigabyte! And it still isn't enough, as if the script totally disregards the PHP memory limit (where?) and even a gigabyte isn't enough!?!?

What can I do? I read about RLimitMEM, but I can not find such a setting anywhere on WAMPServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I searched the project for `memory_limit` and found out, that the composer client attempts to set a memory limit in `system/modules/!composer/src/Runtime.php` There is this line: `@ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` I changed it to `@ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` essentially doubling the available memory, and it worked.

Comment: I have to comment here that I think it is absolutely appalling that a PHP script uses that much memory. I just don't get it.

Comment: It's the dependency resolving part of Composer. Due to the success of the composer package management platform there are __a lot__ of packages in a multitude of versions out there now. Depending on your `composer.json` settings (`minimum-stability`) this results in a large complexity, which in turn requires a lot of memory. See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898 and other tickets for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use the so called *detached mode* for the composer client. If you have a proper CLI environment available, you'll have *no* memory limit and *no* maximum execution time. Also both of these limits can be controlled via command line arguments.

However, this does not work in all hosting environments. See this Wiki entry for more details: https://github.com/contao-community-alliance/composer-client/wiki/Execution-modes