# command "php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle " show this error: VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008]

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.8

Composer worked find yesterday, but today after I trying install: composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle

While run composer update command it show me error:

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Espace insuffisant pour traiter cette commande.

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Espace insuffisant pour traiter cette commande.

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 847249408) (tried to allocate 100663304 bytes) in phar://J:/Projet/foongon/katika.live/katika.live/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 847249408) (tried to allocate 100663304 bytes) in phar://J:/Projet/foongon/katika.live/katika.live/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

I try update composer on my other projects, it is worked fine. After some researching I increased memory_limit: 4096M(also -1) in php.ini file.

I try to run next command: php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krzqT.png) result in attached image Composer error

I try to run next command: php composer.phar diagnose , result in attached image Composer error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WKZo.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The command php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;" => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqh7c.png)

Answer (score 1):

The solution on my installation was to switch from 32bit to 64bit version of PHP. Reason is simple, to get more than 2GB memory available. When I run composer with command:

php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update --profile -vvv

It gives me at the end of success run this result: Memory usage: 322.37MB (peak: 1804.41MB), time: 178.78s

The memory usage is really high and as PHP 32bit has 2GB memory limitation there is no other option. Than you will have no more memory issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase virtual memory [guide](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-2864547/manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows.html). Also please make sure that you have enough free space for allocated virtual memory.

Comment: Yes , I increase my Virtual memory, i have always error memory.
Link screnn Virtual memory : https://www.noelshack.com/2018-22-4-1527739623-memory-size-virtual.png

Comment: @FOKOTHierry make it up to 16GB and make sure you have free space on disc C

Comment: also you can try run command with `php -dmemory_limit=1G ...`

Comment: and maybe this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861627/php-out-of-memory-error-does-not-reflect-memory-limit-setting-in-php-ini?rq=1 can help

Comment: alivo , I have 50 GB Free space on disc C

Comment: i have configure memory_limit in php.ini with Value -1